# Cannot debug with Java extension for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93) extension for Visual Studio 2015, but I can't debug my Java files. I don't know if there is any conflict between extensions, but already tried various methods (disabled all extensions, reinstalling the java compatibility one...). The debug button is disabled, and the green "play" button is rather labeled "Attach...". Thanks in advance.
Even after changing my JDK to 7, I still can't debug.

Comment: What jdk version are you using? Do you have any errors? If so, edit the question and add them

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0_101.
It shows no errors, just won't let me debug the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the extension clearly states that

> Support for the 32- and 64-bit releases of the standard JDK 6 and 7
>   (HotSpot VM)

You will have to switch to another version of the jdk, wait for an update of the extension or simply use a different IDE/editor, I'm afraid.

Comment: I still can't seem to debug, even after changing to JDK 7.